# Getting Error -24 while updating app from play store

Tags: android, google-play

Please give me your best answer why getting an error -24 while updating application
my application name is Druproid.

I am released new version of application and then when i updating the application downloading was performed good but when it install then it give an error Unknown error code during application install: "-24"

Comment: You should attach possible error/issue snap or more detail.

Comment: I am released new version on application and when i update the application downloading was performed good but when it install then it give an error Unknown error code during application install: "-24"

Comment: can you show your manifest file here

Comment: I guess it has nothing to do with you app, may be there is problem with your hardware. search  on google "android installation error code 24"

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be caused by leftover app folders. So for your Druproid add, delete /data/data/com.yarrait.druproid and try installing again, it should work. For people getting the error with other apps, delete the appropriate folder in /data/data/

There's guides on the Internet saying you need to do a factory reset, which will work, of course, but is unnecessary.

Comment: This fixed my issue.  Had to figure out how to root my phone to do it.